# Is there a way to set System property from properties within the main method of a SpringBootApplication class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to set System property from properties within the main method of a SpringBootApplication class?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", “proxy.com");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", “proxy-s.com");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Currently I am hardcoding these values. I would like to pull these values "proxy.com", "proxy-s.com" from the properties file and not hardcode them.